# Does a number field and its Hilbert class field have same conductors??

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

**Definition:** (conductor of a number field)  Let $K$  be a number field with abelian Galois group over $\Bbb Q$. The conductor  $n$ is the smallest even number such that $K\subset \Bbb Q(\zeta_n).$

**Assumption**

The  Hilbert class field $H(K)$ of $K$ is abelian over $\Bbb Q.$

**My attempt:**

Suppose the conductor of  Hilbert class field $H(K)$ different from the conductor of $K.$  Say the conductor of $H(K)$ to be $m$ and the conductor of $K$ to be $n$. clearly $n$ divides $m.$
I think $m$ should have at least one different prime factor $p$ than  $n$, thinking to conclude  the prime above $p $  in $K$ ramifies in $H(K)$.
Any help here very much appreciated.

Comment: You only defined the conductor of number fields that are abelian over $\mathbf Q$ (a subfield of a cyclotomic field is abelian over $\mathbf Q$). While $H(K)$ is abelian over $K$, it need not be abelian over $\mathbf Q$ and thus $H(K)$ need not be in a cyclotomic extension of $\mathbf Q$. For example, if $K = \mathbf Q(\sqrt{-23})$ then $H(K) = K(\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is a root of $x^3 - x - 1$ and $H(K)/\mathbf Q$ is nonabelian Galois extension. And if $K$ itself is not abelian over $\mathbf Q$ then $K$ is not in a cyclotomic field but $H(K)$ still makes sense. Rethink what you want to ask.

Comment: According to this MO answer https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15781/given-a-number-field-k-when-is-its-hilbert-class-field-an-abelian-extension-o, under your assumption, the answer is YES